# Помогите с алгоритмом

Tags: java, алгоритм, xml

Есть текстовый файл`(txt)` которую хочу перевести в xml с простой структурой.Только один тег.Трудности возникли при  добавлении атрибута к тегу.
Есть коллекция в ячейках которого есть числовые значения , они указывают скольким тегам нужно добавлять атрибут.А атрибуты я добавляю по нарастанию.Т.Е. напр. если `int count [] = new int[]{5,3};` то первым пяти тегам нужно добавить атрибут `attr=0` а следующим трем `attr=1`.В итоге должно быть как снизу на xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <item attr="0">
            текст
    </item>
    <item attr="0">
            текст
    </item>
    <item attr="0">
            текст
    </item>
    <item attr="0">
            текст
    </item>
    <item attr="0">
            текст
    </item>
    <item attr="1">
            текст
    </item>
    <item attr="1">
            текст
    </item>
    <item attr="1">
            текст
    </item>
</root>
```

CODE:

```
StaticArrayStrings staticArrayStrings = new StaticArrayStrings();
staticArrayStrings.initList5();

File f = new File("text.txt");
InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(f);
InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new 
InputStreamReader(inputStream);
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);

Element element=null;
int position=0;
int count=0;
int item=0;
String s;

while((s=bufferedReader.readLine())!=null){

    //получаю число,сколько раз нужно пробежаться.         
    item = Integer.valueOf(staticArrayStrings.list5.get(position).toString());
    element = new Element("item");
    element.attr("position",""+position);
    element.appendText(s);

    //вот тут нужна помощь.position нужно инкрементить после того 
    //как цикл пробежался item-й раз.Но если в ячейке  след.число 
    //меньше count то он уже не сработает.Помогите пожалуйста кто чем сможет.
    if(count==item){
          position++;
    }

    count++;
    System.out.println(element);

} System.out.println("общее число строк : "+count);
```

Класс в котором список значений :

```
public class StaticArrayStrings {
    public  List list5 = new ArrayList();
    void initList5(){
        list5.add(3);
        list5.add(2);
        list5.add(3);
        list5.add(2);
        list5.add(1);
        list5.add(165);
        list5.add(206);
        list5.add(75);
        list5.add(129);
        list5.add(109);
        list5.add(123);
        list5.add(111);
        list5.add(43);
        list5.add(52);
        list5.add(99);
        list5.add(128);
        list5.add(111);           

    }
}
```

Comment: А где у Вас в коде исходный массив `int count [] = new int[]{5,3};`?

Comment: Тот arrayList.Щас добавлю.

Comment: int count [] = new int[]{5,3}; Это было для примера..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно завести еще счетчик, который будет указывать сколько элементов из текущей группы Вы израсходовали

```
Element element=null;
int position=0;
int count=0;
int curCnt=0;
// Получаем объем первой группы
int item = Integer.valueOf(staticArrayStrings.list5.get(position).toString());

while((s=bufferedReader.readLine())!=null){
    // Если исчерпали элементы из текущей группы, то 
    if (curCnt == item) {
      // сбрасываем счетчик,
      curCnt = 0;
      // увеличиваем номер группы
      position++;
      // считываем следующий объем
      item = Integer.valueOf(staticArrayStrings.list5.get(position).toString());
    }
    element = new Element("item");
    element.attr("position",""+position);
    element.appendText(s);

    count++;
    curCnt++;  // увеличиваем число использованных элементов
    System.out.println(element);

} System.out.println("общее число строк : "+count);
```

Вместо

```
curCnt++;  // увеличиваем число использованных элементов
```

можно писать

```
item--;
```

и тогда блок проверки условия перепишется так

```
// Если исчерпали элементы из текущей группы, то 
if (item == 0) {
  // увеличиваем номер группы
  position++;
  // считываем следующий объем
  item = Integer.valueOf(staticArrayStrings.list5.get(position).toString());
}
```

А еще лучше так, если в Вашем массиве допускаются нули

```
// Если исчерпали элементы из текущей группы, то 
while (item <= 0) {
  // увеличиваем номер группы
  position++;
  // считываем следующий объем
  item = Integer.valueOf(staticArrayStrings.list5.get(position).toString());
}
```

---

P.S. А почему Вы не пишете так?

```
public List<Integer> list5 = new ArrayList<>();
```

тогда вот эта порнография

```
item = Integer.valueOf(staticArrayStrings.list5.get(position).toString());
```

превратится в такой элегантный код

```
item = staticArrayStrings.list5.get(position);
```

Comment: :-D ..Да просто как то об этом не думал..

Comment: Спс..Но сработало только для первых 3-х строк. К остальным добавил item = 1.Щас отлажу,может получиться..

Comment: @maks_007 Я расширил ответ

Comment: Дай бог вам здоровья...Живите долго!!!!Спасибо огромное..Сработало.